# Pyflink view data inside Jupyter notebook like Head/Show in pandas/pyspark

Tags: jupyter-notebook, apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I'm new with PyFlink and trying to learn. I was using pyflink with jupyter Notebook and performing some basic operations. So when I perform certain operation it return a table location in memory like "<pyflink.table.table.Table at 0x1eeffd773a0>. To view data I need to call to_pandas() method. Is it possible to view data without calling to_pandas(). is there any method available in Pyflink to view processed data. like head in pandas or show/display in pyspark.

Thanks
[image: Snippet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to pyflink table api https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/table/intro_to_table_api/

May be you can use execute or execute_sql to get TableResult, and use collect or print api in TableResult

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the help. execute did work for me however it prints output in terminal is there a way to print the output inside notebook env.